# How to get data from 3 mysql tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 mysql tables which is a) contact_details b) history and c) company.

Now I am getting `family_name` from `contact_details` table based on last 5 `view_id` from `history table`.

My current query is working fine :)

Now I want to get `company_name` data from `company` table which `company.cid` is match with `contact_details.cid`. How can I do this with my following working query ?

**Working Query :**

```
$getViewID2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT 
CD.family_name, t.* FROM contact_details CD 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
    history.*
    FROM history
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
        view_id,
        MAX(view_date) max_view_date
        FROM history 
        WHERE is_save IN (0,1) AND mark_as = 1
        GROUP BY view_id
        ORDER BY max_view_date DESC 
        LIMIT 5
    ) AS latestHistory
    ON history.view_id = latestHistory.view_id AND history.view_date = latestHistory.max_view_date
) AS t
ON CD.cdid = t.view_id ORDER BY CD.family_name ASC");
```

Comment: Doesn't just adding `JOIN company on company.cid = CD.cid` after `ON CD.cdid = t.view_id` do what you need?

Comment: I used it before the`ORDER` keyword, but showing me error message.

Comment: What error message do you get? This worked for me: `ON CD.cdid = t.view_id JOIN company on company.cid = CD.cid ORDER BY CD.family_name ASC`

Comment: Yea it's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Well this completely bombs if the companyid doesn't exist for the contact details but after `CD.cdid = t.view_id` add

```
 , company CY WHERE company.cid = CD.cid
```

And before the `FROM` add

```
, CY.*
```